# Random results after parsing JSON in Objective-C

Tags: xcode, json, parsing, uitableview, nsarray

I need to parse multiple JSON objects from several sources on a remote server and I need to populate UITableView with each value of the single parse:

**The single JSON source, example at h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/A1:**

```
{
  "id": 0001,
  "main": {
    "mainA": 100,
  },
}
```

**The single JSON source, example at h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/A2:**

```
{
  "id": 0002,
  "main": {
    "mainA": 200,
  },
}
```

**The single JSON source, example at h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/A3:**

```
{
  "id": 0003,
  "main": {
    "mainA": 300,
  },
}
```

**Here I alloc and initialize the array containing single URLs:**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        // other stuff

        arrayA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A1", @"A2", @"A3", nil]; //each object A1, A2...An is the single subdirectory of URL for JSON source I need to parse
    }
```

**Parse Method:**

```
- (void)LoadParse { // this method is called by a UIButton

        main = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i=0; i < [arrayA count]; i++) {

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"http://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/%@",[arrayA objectAtIndex:i]]];

            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:5.0];

            AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

            NSMutableDictionary *arrayMain = [JSON valueForKey:@"main"];
            [mainA addObject:[arrayMain objectForKey:@"mainA"]];

            NSLog(@"%@",mainA);

            [table reloadData]; // mainA objects populates rows of UITableView
            [table scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];

            }

            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){

            }];

            [operation start];

            }
    }
```

**RESULTS of NSLog(@"%@",mainA);**

```
1st parsing -> NSLog result = random (100-200-300 or 100-300-200 or 200-300-100 or 200-100-300 or 300-200-100 or 300-100-200)
2nd parsing -> (after a few seconds) NSLog result = random (100-200-300 or 100-300-200 or 200-300-100 or 200-100-300 or 300-200-100 or 300-100-200)
3rd parsing -> (after other few seconds) NSLog result = random (100-200-300 or 100-300-200 or 200-300-100 or 200-100-300 or 300-200-100 or 300-100-200)
...
```

**THE ERROR**: as u can see every time I press the UIButton and start parsing I get a DIFFERENT SEQUENCE of mainA objects (then in the table rows), example: after the first parsing, what do I expect? 100-200-300.. and instead no, I get 100-300-200 or 300-200-100, or others, and so in the next parsing, every time I load the parseMethod I get random sequence of mainA, while I can assure that on the REMOTE server A1-A2-A3 mainA objects are respectively 100-200-300. So, can u help me, what is wrong here? I'm losing my head, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you proceed through the loop, you issue an *asynchronous* request to the server. Each request has a completion block which is executed when the result arrives back from the webserver, but because these are asynchronous, you have no idea the order they will be executed in (whichever server response arrives first will be processed first in it's completion block).

To fix this you can pre-fill your array when you declare it:

```
    main = [@[@"A",@"B",@"C"] mutableCopy];
```

Then in your loop you can allocate each response to it's respective position in the array:

```
        [main replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[arrayMain objectForKey:@"mainA"]];
```

You should pre-fill the array as you cannot add an object at an index greater than the existing length of the array.

*edit* I am not clear the relationship in your code between `arrayA` (which you do pre-populate), `main`, and `mainA`, but I am sure you can get the principle.

Comment: So what can I do? the for () loop is wrong? There is other code to get results every time in the precise order? Thanks!

Comment: @Huxley, see my updated answer. When using the array you will need to check it's contents, as you will not be able to guarantee a successful result from each network request.

Comment: @Huxley, see also  my edit... I am a little confused by your use of `main`, `mainA` and `arrayA`, but I think you can get this to work without too much trouble.

Comment: Thank you, I have tested your code... the problem now is that NSLog result is, randomly: 100,A,200,300,B,C or 100,200,300,A,B,C or 100,A,B,200,C,300 or other every parsing...

Comment: @Huxley, sorry it should be `replaceObjectAtIndex`, i've updated my answer.

Comment: PERFECT! @He Was, this is the solution! Thank you very much! Last question: in your opinion before main = [@[@"A",@"B",@"C"] mutableCopy]; I must write also main = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; or it is not necessary?

Comment: @Huxley, not necessary, you have created it with `mutableCopy`