# Random order of results (again) after parsing JSON in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, for-loop, nsarray

I need to parse again multiple JSON strings from several sources on a remote server and I need to populate UITableView with each value of the single parse: [thanks to @He was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609836/random-results-after-parsing-json-in-objective-c) for the previous answer.

**The single JSON source, example at h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/A1:**

```
{
  "id": 0001,
  "main": {
    "mainA": 100,
  },
}
```

**The single JSON source, example at h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/A2:**

```
{
  "id": 0002,
  "main": {
    "mainA": 200,
  },
}
```

**The single JSON source, example at h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/A3:**

```
{
  "id": 0003,
  "main": {
    "mainA": 300,
  },
}
```

**GOAL:** PARSING EACH VALUE OF mainA AND GET THEM IN THE RIGHT ORDER A1->A2->A3

**The array of single URLs where we can parse the remote JSON string:**

```
idURL = [[NSArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"A1", @A2", @A3", nil];
```

**Parsing, [thanks to @Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602556/detect-real-end-of-the-for-loop-in-objective-c), I need blocks 'cos I MUST wait the END to call theGreatMethod:**

```
- (void)parsingJSON { // starts with a UIButton pressed!

    mainA = [@[@"1",@"2",@"3"] mutableCopy]; // defined here to preserve right order of mainA objects after parsing

    int mainACount = 0;

    typedef void (^AFJSONSuccessBlock) (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON);
    typedef void (^AFJSONFailureBlock) (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON);

    __block int numRequests = [idURL count];

    AFJSONSuccessBlock onSuccess = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dictMain = [JSON objectForKey:@"main"];
        [mainA replaceObjectAtIndex:mainACount withObject:[dictMain objectForKey:@"mainA"]];

        mainACount ++; // EVERY AFJSONRequestOperation *operation int mainACount = mainACount + 1 
        numRequests --; // EVERY AFJSONRequestOperation *operation int numRequest = numRequest - 1

        if (numRequests == 0) {

            NSLog(@"END PARSING");
            NSLog(@"FINAL mainA ORDER: %@",mainA);

        [self theGreatMethod]; // a method to populate UITableView with mainA results

        }
    };

    AFJSONFailureBlock onFailure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error userInfo]);

        numRequests--;

        if (numRequests == 0) {

         NSLog(@"ERROR PARSING");
            [self theGreatMethod]; // a method to populate UITableView with mainA results

        }
    };

    for (NSString* jsonPath in idURL) {

        NSString* absolutePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"h**p://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/%@", jsonPath];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:absolutePath];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
        operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                    success:onSuccess
                                                                    failure:onFailure];
        [operation start];

    }

        NSLog(@"START PARSING");

}
```

I have in this situation defined a **int mainACount** to count each AFJSONRequestOperation *operation cycle and to replace mainA object one bye one, but I'm not sure this is the right way; I've tried also for (int i=0; i < [mainA count]; i++) and [mainA replaceObjectAtIndex:i] loop but I have the same, wrong, results.

**RESULTS of NSLog(@"FINAL mainA ORDER: %@",mainA);**

```
1st parsing -> NSLog result = random (100-200-300 or 100-300-200 or 200-300-100 or 200-100-300 or 300-200-100 or 300-100-200)
2nd parsing -> (after a few seconds) NSLog result = random (100-200-300 or 100-300-200 or 200-300-100 or 200-100-300 or 300-200-100 or 300-100-200)
3rd parsing -> (after other few seconds) NSLog result = random (100-200-300 or 100-300-200 or 200-300-100 or 200-100-300 or 300-200-100 or 300-100-200)
...
```

**THE ERROR**: as u can see every time I press the UIButton and start parsing I get AGAIN a DIFFERENT SEQUENCE of mainA objects (then different values in the table rows), example: after the first parsing, what do I expect? 100-200-300, instead its random... So, can u help me again, what is wrong here? **OR, there is a BETTER way to do that parsing in the right order?**

Comment: Why not just apply a sort to your data before you display it?

Comment: Well, with the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609836/random-results-after-parsing-json-in-objective-c answer I was able to sort precise order of data, I cannot understand because HERE I can't do it again! What do u mean? Can u provide some code?

Comment: Have you tried logging any intermediate results, to see what order you're actually receiving things?  Why do you call "arrayMain" an NSMutableDictionary??

Comment: sure @HotLicks I tried loggin intermediate results: results are 100,2,3 - 100,200,3 - 100,200,300 then (for the next parsing) 200,2,3 - 200,100,3 - 200,100,300 then random and similar

Comment: Have you tried not sorting until everything's been downloaded?  Have you tried putting enter/exit logs in the block, to see what concurrency does to you?

Comment: What do u mean with "until everything's been downloaded"? I am constrained to sort with replaceObjectAtIndex: INTO the block because I need to parse single values of mainA for EACH idURL object (its a sort of parsing on parsing).. are there another way to sort data?

Comment: I mean, wait until downloading is complete.

Comment: Good point: please can u provide or suggest me some code to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the array of URLs like this:

```
idURL = [[NSArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"A1", @"A2", @"A3", nil];
```

Even if the `for` loop parses the objects in order, as you use an `NSArray`, the order in which your calls to `AFJSONRequestOperation` will return the results is not guaranteed, because it's an asynchronous request.

You might want to lock the thread with the [@synchronized directive](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html):

```
- (void)parsingJSON:(id)anObj
{
    // ...
    AFJSONSuccessBlock onSuccess = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // ...
        @synchronized(anObj)
        {
            // Everything between the braces is protected by the @synchronized directive.
            var2 ++; // EVERY AFJSONRequestOperation *operation int var2 = var2 + 1 
            numRequests --; // EVERY AFJSONRequestOperation *operation int numRequest = numRequest - 1
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Alex, unluckly it was already idURL = [[NSArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"A1", @"A2", @"A3", nil]; I have done a transcription error.

Comment: I have now read your edited answer but as u can see from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609836/random-results-after-parsing-json-in-objective-c answer its possible get values in the right order (prefill array), also with AFJSONRequestOperation. I cannot do again that in THIS new situation.